# SetInt 9h, KbdEvent (What's this)??? (MASM)

Tags: assembly, dos, interrupt, masm, drivers

Can someone tell me what these two lines are doing in the code (of a DOS keyboard driver)?

```
GetInt 9h,OldKbdEvent
SetInt 9h,KbdEvent
```

`OldKbdEvent` is defined elsewhere in the code like this:
    `OldKbdEvent DD ?`
`KbdEvent` exists as a label elsewhere in the code. These are the only instances of these symbols being defined.

After these two lines, the code makes an interrupt 27h to DOS (Terminate and stay resident) which means DOS terminates the program but keeps it in memory to resume it at a later moment.

Comment: Can you show us the code that appears after the label `KbdEvent` . My guess `KbdEvent` is code that represents the interrupt routine that will be used when keyboard interrupts occur. I would guess it would also chain to `OldKbdEvent` since it will be operating as a TSR.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the code, I expect that you should find a pair of macros, `GetInt` and `SetInt`. Going on the names, these will fetch or store a value to the interrupt table, located at 0000:0000 - You're dealing with Int 0x09, so they will be accessing 0000:(0x9 * 4)

Basically, they're getting and setting the values in the int table for the keyboard handling int. The 16bit table consists of 256 entries of 4 bytes each- 2 for the segment and 2 for the offset. When the cpu receives an int, it looks up the address in this table before transferring execution to that point.

Here's some code that does what I imagine SetInt does:

```
cli                             ;no interruptions
mov bx, 0x09                    ;hardware interrupt #
shl bx, 2                       ;multiply by 4
xor ax, ax
mov gs, ax                      ;start of memory
mov [gs:bx], word keyhandler
mov [gs:bx+2], ds               ; segment
sti
```

Comment: A note to the reader: Using `gs`(or `fs`) segment would restrict the program to an 80386 or later processor. These segment registers weren't available on the 286/186/86/88.

Comment: It seems like you were right. There is a macro named GetInt and anotherone named SetInt. However, it doesn't explain the sending of an undefined variable KbdEvent to the SetInt macro. The macro looks like this: `SetInt                MACRO Num,Ofs
     MOV AX,2500H+Num
     MOV DX,OFFSET Ofs
     INT 21H
     ENDM`                 Instead of changing the interrupt table directly as in your example, it uses the DOS INT 21h subfunction 25h to change it. Could it be that since there is no defined variable by name KbdEvent, it sends the address of the label instead?

Comment: @user504882 - :) - Yep, this macro does indeed send the address (or offset) of the KbdEvent label. However, the ds:dx passed to int21h-25h has to be the address of the new handler. So, if the KbdEvent label isn't at the start of a block of code, bad things (tm) will happen when the ints called. That tells me that either some code gets copied to thus address or that it has data immediately following it - data which is actually code disguised by the use of db, dw or dd etc. Not sure, its difficult to make constructive guesses without seeing more of the code.